# Allowing Azure CDN to access Azure KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-cdn

I'm trying to set up my `Azure CDN` endpoint to use `HTTPS` for the custom domain I already set up.

When I tried to point at the `SSL` cert in my `Azure KeyVault`, I got an error stating that I need to grant `Azure CDN` access to `KeyVault`. Any idea how I can do this -- hopefully through the Portal and NOT Powershell, though I have a feeling it'll end up requiring Powershell commands.

Basically, I'm trying to get my `Azure CDN` endpoint to use the `SSL` cert in my `Azure KeyVault`.

Anyway, I'd appreciate someone pointing to me an article or a set of instructions please. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instructions for enabling SSL with your own certificate stored in Azure KeyVault are described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-2-enable-https-with-your-own-certificate#ssl-certificates.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav! We spoke a while ago. Hope all's well with you!

Comment: Indeed. It has been really long. Hope all's well with you too.

Comment: So, when it says to "Register Azure CDN as an app in your Azure Active Directory via PowerShell", where do I get that GUID it's referencing?  I tried that, verbatim, and I got the error "New-AzADServicePrincipal: When using this permission, the backing application of the service principal being created must in the local tenant"

Comment: @EdH...Please post a new question and provide all details there. Thanks.

Comment: No worries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206432/how-to-register-your-azure-resource-as-an-application-in-azure-active-directory

Answer (score 1):

There's something broken with this lately.

Azure tells you to do the thing that doesn't work:
`New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "205478c0-bd83-4e1b-a9d6-db63a3e1e1c8" -Role Contributor`

If you're curious as to what it actually does, it just gives the **hidden** `Microsoft.AzureFrontDoor-Cdn` the role `Contributor` in your subscription's IAM. You can view it in the portal:

[image]

It seems that the "Contributor" role no longer contains the necessary permissions to read keyvaults - namely the `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/readMetadata/action` permission.

I've noticed that:

- this permission is given to the built in `Key Vault Secrets User` role
- all the roles that seem "superior" to the secrets user like `Key Vault Administrator` don't work, it HAS to be `Key Vault Secrets User`

So what fixed it for me is going into my keyvault and giving **MYSELF** (not azure cdn) the permission to read and list secrets. Seems that even as owner and god-emperor of your azure instance you can't access secrets by default ("AT" is me in the screenshot):

[image]