# How to register your Azure resource as an Application in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cdn

I have an Azure CDN.  It has a custom domain, and I attempting to register my own certificate for HTTPS support.

I am attempting to follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-2-enable-https-with-your-own-certificate

I have uploaded my Certificate to a Key Vault.  That should be good.  I am now trying grant my Azure CDN Profile access to my Key Vault in order for it to get the certificate.  That is this step in the tutorial (Register Azure CDN, step #2)

[image]

That step shows a GUID (205478c0-bd83-4e1b-a9d6-db63a3e1e1c8).  Where is that coming from?  Is that the identifier for my Azure CDN Profile?  If so, where would I get that?

I also just noticed there are two commands there:  The text shows New-AzADServicePrincipal, but the screenshot shows New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal.  Presumably, the latter is the (older?) command based on Resource Manager.  But, which one should I be using?

Also, I don't think I have Azure Powershell installed.  Can I do this using Cloud Shell via the Azure Portal?

What I see when I attempt to run the command from Cloud Shell

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That step shows a GUID (205478c0-bd83-4e1b-a9d6-db63a3e1e1c8). Where is that coming from? Is that the identifier for my Azure CDN Profile? If so, where would I get that?

The GUID is the `Application ID` of the multi-tenant AD App in the Microsoft tenant(`microsoft.onmicrosoft.com`), when you use the `New-AzADServicePrincipal` with the GUID, it will create a service principal related to this AD App in your AAD tenant, which represents your CDN.

When you run the `New-AzADServicePrincipal` successfully, you could find it in the portal -> `Azure Active Directory` -> `Enterprise applications` in your tenant.

[image]

> I also just noticed there are two commands there: The text shows New-AzADServicePrincipal, but the screenshot shows New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal. Presumably, the latter is the (older?) command based on Resource Manager. But, which one should I be using?

The `New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal` belongs to the old [`AzureRM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/overview?view=azurermps-6.13.0) module, `New-AzADServicePrincipal` belongs to the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) module. You could use both of them, but I recommend you to use `New-AzADServicePrincipal`, because the `AzureRM` module was deprecated and will not be updated any more.

> Also, I don't think I have Azure Powershell installed. Can I do this using Cloud Shell via the Azure Portal?

Of course, you can. Just run that in the cloud shell, no need to install any module manually.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed response.  It is very helpful.  When I try calling New-AzADServicePrincipal with a GID I generated as the application id, I get the following message "When using this permission, the backing application of the service principal being created must in the local tenant".  Does that mean that I do not have permissions to create this service principal?

Comment: @EdH You mean you generate the GUID? In this case, no need to generate the GUID by yourself, just use `New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId 205478c0-bd83-4e1b-a9d6-db63a3e1e1c8` without changing anything.

Comment: Thanks again.  I still get the same message when I use the command as above.  I have put the screenshot in my question above.

Comment: @EdH I will have a test and back to you.

Comment: If I check my applications in AAD, I can see the CDN as an application.  Whether or not I put it there, it looks like I should be able to progress.  And your explaination helped me understand that.  Thank you again,

Comment: @EdH Yes, if the app is already in the Enterprise application, you will no need to create it again.

Comment: @EdH And about the error, I can reproduce it with a normal user account, it works with an admin account, the normal user should have no permission to do that by default.